# Ffmpeg - Audio synch problem after cutting the video (Debian Server)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am having (apparently random) problems with ffmpeg when cutting and joining some video clips on our Debian server. The audio of the video we generate by joining different clips is out-of-synch, even though nor the original one, not the generated clips are not. This happens with ffmpeg version 3.2.15-0+deb9u4.

We are wondering if the problem could be related to an wrong combination cutting / set keyframe, but we can't go any further.

Here the code used to cut and join the videos:

```
create clip

ffmpeg -y -ss ' . $ss . ' -i ' . $i . ' -t ' . $t . ' -c copy ' . $tempfile . ' 2>&1'));// read duration$duration = floatval(shell_exec('ffprobe -i ' . $tempfile . ' -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" 2>&1'));// set key frameecho nl2br(shell_exec('ffmpeg -y -i ' . $tempfile . ' -r 5 -force_key_frames ' . $ss . ' -copyts ' . $o . ' 2>&1'

create clip from image

self::getNiceOption() . 'ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -loop 1 -i ' . $imagePath . ' -c:v libx264 -r 5 -t ' . $duration . ' -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=' . $res_x . ':' . $res_y . ' ' . $o . ' 2>&1'

join clips

// scale each clip to same resolution
self::getNiceOption() . 'ffmpeg -y -i ' . $path . ' -vf "scale=' . $res_x . ':' . $res_y . ':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=' . $res_x . ':' . $res_y . ':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" ' . $scaledVideoPath . ' 2>&1'

// concat the clips
self::getNiceOption() . 'ffmpeg -y -safe 0 -f concat -i ' . $text_file_path . ' ' . $o . ' 2>&1'
```

Here the problem, i guess:

[mp4 @ 0x55fcd555c720] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 16116000, current: 14824181; changing to 16116001. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

Thanks!

Comment: All clips to be concatenated must have the same attributes. Your scripting is hiding your actual ffmpeg commands, and you did not provide the complete logs from each command, so we can't provide a specific answer.

Comment: [mp4 @ 0x55fcd555c720] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 16116000, current: 14824181; changing to 16116001. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

Comment: Need: 1) to see each command, unscripted with no variables. 2) The complete log from each command.